# Remove line item from query based on character in a string, sql

Tags: sql-server, select, casting

I have an sql query and I need to remove specific rows based on the third to last number in a varchar generated in my query. The query is taking a small date time in the format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" and turning it into a varchar. For example: The date "2015-05-04 06:03:00" would become the varchar 05040603. I need to remove any line item where the third to last varchar digit is 9, 1, 4, or 0. Here is my current code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(M, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) 
    + RIGHT ('0' + Cast(DATEPART(DD, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) 
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HH, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) 
    + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) AS 'VarChar Number', 
    ColA, DateTime 
FROM 
    TableA 
WHERE 
    ColB IS NOT NULL 
    AND DateTime NOT IN (SELECT DateTime From TableB) 
    AND DateTime NOT IN (SELECT DateTime From tableC 
                         WHERE DateTime IS NOT NULL)
```

In this example table A has my small date time and the `varchar` number is being generated from it. ColA is from Table A and is just information. The Where statement is just cross comparing the date time to other tables to remove it based on if the date already appears in those tables.

Comment: Which type of SQL are you using? Microsoft, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL?

Comment: Microsoft, specifically SQL Server Management Studio. However, I will be dropping the code into a vb.net program and filling a datagridview with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(M, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) +
    RIGHT ('0' + Cast(DATEPART(DD, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HH, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) +
    RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) AS 'VarChar Number',
    ColA,
    DateTime
FROM
    TableA
WHERE
    ColB IS NOT NULL AND
    DateTime NOT IN (SELECT DateTime From TableB) AND
    DateTime NOT IN (SELECT DateTime From tableC WHERE DateTime IS NOT NULL) AND
    RIGHT(CAST(DATEPART(HH, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 1) NOT IN ('0', '1', '4', '9')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring` to do this.

```
select * from 
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(M, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) 
+ RIGHT ('0' + Cast(DATEPART(DD, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) 
+ RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(HH, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) 
+ RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, TableA.DateTime) AS varchar), 2) AS [VarChar Number], 
ColA, DateTime FROM TableA WHERE ColB IS NOT NULL 
AND DateTime NOT IN (SELECT DateTime From TableB) 
AND DateTime NOT IN (SELECT DateTime From tableC WHERE DateTime IS NOT NULL)
) t
where substring([VarChar Number], 6, 1) not in ('0','1','4','9')
```

Comment: This could work however I would rather do my selection off the original datetime column versus the generated one. Thanks!

Comment: @vkp I think you needed the eighth character and not the sixth. I had to read closer too, but the `varchar` version didn't include seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
WHERE 
    ColB IS NOT NULL 
    AND DateTime NOT IN (SELECT DateTime From TableB) 
    AND DateTime NOT IN (SELECT DateTime From tableC 
                         WHERE DateTime IS NOT NULL)
    and datepart(minute, TableA.DateTime) % 10 not in (0, 1, 4, 9)
```

I don't think there's any reason to mess around with string values, just extract the minute and work with that. It's clearer to understand the intentions and avoids problems as with vkp's answer and accidentally looking at the 6th position rather than the 8th.